# Publish non-@Instantiate OSGi service with iPOJO

Tags: java, osgi, ipojo

I have OSGi modular system in which i have the following components:

- Some specific protocol instance implementation, which represent a connection via specfic protocol to the specific server (instantiated per connection service)
- Some specific protocol instances manager service, creating and pre-configuring instances on demand (multiple singletone services from, normally, different bundles)
- Connection manager which aggregates protocol manager services and asking them to provide protocol instances when needed (single singletone service)

They are packaged into OSGi bundles as follows:

```
`-ConnectionManager
      `-ConnectionManager.class
`-IrcProtocol
      `-IrcProtocolManagerService.class
      `-IrcProtocolInstance.class
`-XMPPProtocol
      `-XMPPProtocolManagerService.class
      `-XMPPProtocolInstance.class
```

---

The `ConnectionManager` is annotated with

```
@Provides
@Instantiate
@Component
```

And implements `Subscriber` interface, which enbles it with ability to send and listen on messages delivered trhough some sort of typed `Event Admin`.

---

Each `*ProtocolManager` is annotated with

```
@Provides
@Instantiate
@Component
```

And implements `ProtocolManager` interface which enables it's discovery by `ConnectionManager` service listener.

---

Each `*ProtocolInstance` is annoteted with

```
@Provides
@Component
```

And implements `Subscriber` interface. Also it implements `ProtocolInstance` interface, which offers such generic connection operations as `connect()` and `disconnect()`.

---

The problem here is that `ProtocolInstance`s are created by hand, with `new` operator, inside of `ProtocolManager`, not by `@Instantiate` annotation trigger, and because of that - do not participate in iPOJO service publishing, despite it's `@Provides` annotation.

---

The question: how to correctly (and preferably declaratively, with annotations) publish this programmatically created `ProtocolListener` services without manually diving into raw OSGi service publication (at least outside some sort of factory, maybe)? Or, probably, how to re-structure my system in order to have it better playing along with the unspoken iPOJO guidelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPOJO does not support creating object with 'new'. Indeed, an iPOJO instance is not only this objects, but also the container wrapping it.

However, you have two solutions:

- using the BundleContext
  (http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-ipojo/apache-felix-ipojo-userguide/ipojo-faq.html#injecting-the-bundle-context-in-a-pojo)
  to register your objects
- use the Factory service to create instances on the fly
  (http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-ipojo/apache-felix-ipojo-userguide/ipojo-advanced-topics/ipojo-factory-service.html)